# Como listar apenas nome e data dos documentos usando o comando dir?

Tags: cmd, batch, ms-dos, bat

Como gerar um arquivo csv listando apenas nome e data dos arquivos dentro de um determinado diretório.

Visto que não há  qualquer opção no comando `dir`, que me gere uma saída com apenas esses dados.

A maioria traz um cabeçalho e o tamanho dos arquivos.

Estou usando was comando:

```
dir "\\diretorio_origem\*.pdf"  > \\diretorio_destino\lista_arquivos.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

---

> - **Update**: usando **`forfiles`** para obter data e nome dos arquivos:

```bat
forfiles /m *.* /c "cmd /c echo/@fdate;@file"
```

---

> - **Resulta:** **`16-04-2019,"Arquivos.ext"`**

---

O comando poderia ser um **`dir`** + um duplo **`for`**, e usando o **delimitador** configurado no **sistema**...

Porque ocorre que um arquivo **CVS**, tem um o seguinte **layout**:

> - **`dado+delimitador+dado...` | ficando: | `01/01/2001;nome_arquivo.ext`**

```bat
:: para identificar/ler o delimitador configurado no sistema (para caso o usuário tenha alterado) via linha de comando ::
set _hkey=HKCU\Control Panel\International  & for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %i in ('reg query "%_hkey%" ^| findstr /lc:"sList"') do set _delimitador=%i

:: para identificar o delimator configurado via bat ::
set _hkey=HKCU\Control Panel\International
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%i in ('reg query "%_hkey%" ^| findstr /lc:"sList"') do set _delimitador=%%i
```

---

```bat
:: na linha de comando ::
type nul > \\diretorio_destino\lista_arquivos.csv & set _hkey=HKCU\Control Panel\International  & for /f "tokens=3delims= " %D in ('reg query "%_hkey%" ^| findstr /lc:"sList"')do for /f "tokens=1,5delims= " %i in ('dir /tc /a-d^|find "/"')do echo/%i%D%j>>\\diretorio_destino\lista_arquivos.csv 

:: no arquivo bat ::
type nul > \\diretorio_destino\lista_arquivos.csv & set _hkey=HKCU\Control Panel\International  & for /f "tokens=3delims= " %%D in ('reg query "%_hkey%" ^| findstr /lc:"sList"')do for /f "tokens=1,5delims= " %%i in ('dir /tc /a-d^|find "/"')do echo/%%i%%D%%j>>\\diretorio_destino\lista_arquivos.csv
```

> - **Resulta:** **`16/04/2019;Arquivos.ext`**